# Mongo Db - How to Iterate over aggregate function and convert collection to individual fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have 2 mongo db collections and i am trying to create a Report view..

I am trying to link these two tables to create a flat table structure for reporting purpose. For sake of simplicity, lets assume My **Collection 1**   Lets call it "user"  as below

```
{"_id": LUUID("958cf136-c820-bc48-ad7d-b3795fa47e8b"),
  "UserData": {
    "Userid": "5296783",
    "UserName": "John Mathew",
    "User DOB" : "1985-05-22"
} }
```

This is my **Collection 2:**  -called as  UserHistory

```
  {
    "_id": "09018481-0e88-4b44-b0dc-000dff7ba618",
    "User Reference Id": "5296783",
    "History": [
      {
        "Page Visited": "Home.html",
        "Visit StartTime": "2016-05-12T02:33:37.072Z",
        "Visit EndTime": "2016-05-12T03:33:37.072Z"
      },
      {
        "Page Visited": "About.html",
        "Visit StartTime": "2016-05-12T02:33:37.072Z",
        "Visit EndTime": "2016-05-12T03:33:37.072Z"
      },
      {
        "Page Visited": "Career.html",
        "Visit StartTime": "2016-05-12T02:33:37.072Z",
        "Visit EndTime": "2016-05-12T03:33:37.072Z"
      }
    ]  }
```

This is the output i am trying to achieve  :

[image]

**Now the question** : How do i iterate through the collection of History to create a flat structure? I am using aggregate but not sure how to use the for loop.

This is my query. i want to change the field "USer History" to individual fields

```
  db.User.aggregate([
{$lookup: {
        from: "UserHistory", 
        localField: "Userid"
        foreignField: "User Reference Id"
        as: "UserHistoryView"}
          },
      {$project: {

    "User Id":    $UserData.UserId,
    "User Name" : $UserData.UserName,
    "User DOB" :  $UserData.USerDob, 
    "User History" : "UserHistoryView"
     }} 
    ])
```

*Note: This is a dummy collection. Real scenario is much more complex. Used this sample for explaining. The aggregate function works. so pls ignore any syntax or typo errors.*

Comment: Any help would be great help :(

Comment: you can unwind on UserHistoryView and after group by UserId

Comment: @chf would you happen to have any reference links?  I am new to Mongo DB and find it little different than our traditional SQL

Comment: $unwind (to deconstruct an array field) you have to use this aggregation stage after $project: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/ so you have to use $group to regroup as you want: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/